# drawing two consecutive triangle in c

Tags: c

Take two base length input and draw two triangles in consecutive, the rest drawing two triangles in consecutive with two inputs of base length of triangles. But my code works for only one triangle (spaces are filled with `.` for clarity).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,sum=1,i,a,b,z;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    z=x;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
     {if (sum>x)
       break;
      for (b=1;b<z;b++)
       printf(" ");
       z=z-1;
      for (a=1;a<=sum;a++)
       printf("*");
      printf("\n");
      sum=sum+2;
      }

    return 0;

}
```

This outputs

```
....................*
...................***
..................*****
.................*******
................*********
...............***********
..............*************
.............***************
............*****************
...........*******************
..........*********************
```

and the expected output with an input of 7 and 21 is:

```
.................*..........
................***.........
...............*****........
..............*******.......
.............*********......
............***********.....
...........*************....
...*......***************...
..***....*****************..
.*****..*******************.
****************************
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please use the edit button to fix your question.

Comment: @Riccado What are the "two base length" and could you show how the triangles should look?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow inputs are 7 and 21 which are base lengths of the triangles.the first triangle has 7 stars at the base.the second has 21 stars at the base.but my code can only produce one triangle. i tried to put another triangle but not working..can u see the image??

Comment: what is the output when you enter a even number for eg:4

Comment: The first real problem I see is you only ask for one number, where the assignment is to ask for *two*.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Nice username you have :D

Answer (score 0):

It is a very difficukt assignment especially for begiiners (like me:)).

If I have understood correctly then you need the following. Take into account that I used a compiler that supports C99.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        size_t m = 0;

        printf( "Enter the base length of the first triangle: " );
        scanf( "%zu", &n );

        if ( n == 0 ) break;

        printf( "Enter the base length of the second triangle: " );
        scanf( "%zu", &m );

        if ( m == 0 ) break;

        puts( "" );

        char left[n + 1];
        char right[m + 1];

        memset( left, '*', n );
        memset( right, '*', m );

        left[n]  = '\0';
        right[m] = '\0';

        size_t max = n < m ? m : n;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < max; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%-*s %*s\n", n, left, m, right );
            if ( i < n ) left[n - i - 1] = '\0';
            if ( i < m ) right[m - i - 1] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter 7 and 21 as you pointed out in a comment for your post then the output will look like

```
******* *********************
******   ********************
*****     *******************
****       ******************
***         *****************
**           ****************
*             ***************
               **************
                *************
                 ************
                  ***********
                   **********
                    *********
                     ********
                      *******
                       ******
                        *****
                         ****
                          ***
                           **
                            *
```

**Edit**: You should initially formulate your question correctly. After uodating your post I see that it was changed essentially.

Comment: The two triangles need to be aligned at the bottom. Still .. you're right. What *appeared* to be yet another [silly triangle question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+print+triangle+is%3Aq) is not as simple as it looks.

Comment: @Jongware  I think it will be not difficult to modify the program I showed that to output the triangles with aligned bottoms.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int n;
    int small, big;

    printf("Input length of total: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);//check omit, two input ? your's one.
    small = n / 4;
    big = small * 3;

    int total = small + big;
    int height = (big - 1) / 2 + 1;
    char canvas[height][total];

    memset(canvas, '0', sizeof(canvas));
    int i, v, h;
    for(i=0, v = height; i<height; ++i){
        int len;

        --v;
        len = small - i * 2;
        if(len > 0)
            memset(&canvas[v][i], '*', len);
        len = big - i * 2;
        if(len > 0)
            memset(&canvas[v][small + i], '*', len);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    for(v = 0; v < height; ++v){
        for(h = 0; h < total; ++h)
            putchar(canvas[v][h]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I do without using arrays?

Comment: @Riccado You select in the position(v lines, h character) to write(putchar) '*' or '0' or '\n'.

Comment: For example in my code, the range  is range of writes '*' by memset .

Comment: You used array to draw the canvas. How can I draw canvas in the other way without using arrays??

Comment: I explained in the previous comment already. `if(Position_should_write(v, h)==true) putchar('*'); else putchar('0');`

Comment: Can you explain more? more examples??

Comment: @Riccado ie `memset(&canvas[v][i], '*', len);` meant should write '*' from (v,i) to (v, i+len-1).